# I need to know how to sort my dictionary on python by aveage scores with students with multi-ple scores?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, average

I have scores of names of pupils in my class who took a quiz. ome took more than one and I want to work out the average using python. I saved the scores in a textfile but im not sure how to programme it so it sorts it by there total scores divided by the amount of times they took there test. im using python 3.4.1.

```
the text file looks like this : 
zor:10
zor:21
bob:30
qwerty:46
```

and I have tried to sort it by this :

```
 if schClass == '2':
     schClass = open("scores2.txt", 'r')
     li = open("scores2.txt", 'r')
     data = li.read().splitlines()
     for li in data:
        name = li.split(":")[0]
        score = li.split(":")[1]
        if name not in diction1:
            diction1[name] = score
        elif name in diction1  :
            diction1[name] = (score) + (diction1[name])
            for name in diction1:
                diction1[name] = int(diction1[name])/3
```

Comment: And, What does the code do?

Comment: I think your dictionary should be in the form `{"name": [score1, score2, score3]}` and that you should first load all the scores in the dictionary, and when this is complete, cycle through all the names to report the means.

Comment: Just prints the normal textfile without working out the average

Comment: it cant be that way as a different programme generates the names and scores like that,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your dictionary have the following structure:

```
diction1 = {'zor': [10, 21,], 'bob': [30]}
```

Then create a new dictionary where you store the name, and the average score:

```
averages_dct = {'zor': 15.5, }
```

Your code should look something like this:

```
diction1 = {'john': [10, 20], 'mary': [12,], 'chris': [10, 20]}

# Contains names as keys and average as values.
averages_dct = {}

for name in diction1:
    student_average = sum(diction1[name]) / len(diction1[name])

    # Store the value:
    averages_dct.update({name: student_average})


# Dict containing averages as keys and names as values
# (inserting averages first)
reversed_dct = {averages_dct[k]: [] for k in averages_dct}

# (matching names)
for average in reversed_dct:
    for name in averages_dct:
        if average == averages_dct[name]:

            # Adds name of student if he has this average
            reversed_dct[average].append(name)

# Prints the results from highest to lowest.
for av in sorted(reversed_dct, reverse=True):
    print('average: %s, students: %s' % (av, reversed_dct[av]))
```

Answer (score 0):

can this helps you?

```
def dataload():
#This is just to load your data into a custom dictionary, for simplicity
#i wrote example data into a string, you can use your I/O logic 
    test="zor:10\n\
zor:21\n\
bob:30\n\
qwerty:46\n\
zor:24"
    dictionary = {}
    d = test.splitlines()
    for i in d:
        values = i.split(':')
        name  = values[0]
        score = float(values[1])
        if name not in dictionary:
            dictionary[name] = [score]
        else:
            l = dictionary[name]
            l.append(score)            
            dictionary[name] = l
    return dictionary


def printdictionary(d):
#This is shows the content of your custom dictionary
    for item in d.keys():
        l = d[item]
        avg = 0
        for exam in l:
            avg = avg + exam
        avg = avg / len(l)
        print(item," => ", d[item]," => ", avg)

dictionary = dataload()
printdictionary(dictionary)    

# output:
#bob  =>  [30.0]  =>  30.0
#zor  =>  [10.0, 21.0, 24.0]  =>  18.333333333333332
#qwerty  =>  [46.0]  =>  46.0
```

The idea behind this code is the following: in dataload method python reads exams from textfile (strings or somewhere else) and put them into a dictionary in which value is a list of exams evaluation. While in printdictionary method the average score is calculated and the result is shown to user.